# Create Own Module I Can Use On Terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I'm working on a mac terminal and I'm creating some simple commands that I can run anywhere. These are mostly to do things I repeatedly do in one simple command, so I don't have to type it out every time. Some examples:

`alias changetocertaindestination="cd ~/repos/certaindestination"`

```
opencertainfile() {
open ~/repos/mydestination/certainfile.txt
}
```

I would like to know how to make it so I can use the notation that other modules/packages(I'm not sure what they are called) use, i.e. `git branch` , instead of `gitbranch`

So instead of every prefacing every alias with `changeto`, and using `changetodestination` I can use `changeto destination`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to parameterize your functions.

```
changeto () {
  cd -- ~/repos/"$1"
}

$ changeto certaindestination
$ pwd
/home/alex/repos/certaindestination
```

Comment: The actual paths are longer, so I'm using keywords for the entire paths. Would I just use an if/else chain to turn the short keywords into the longer paths based on the input?

Comment: I would use a `case` statement instead, but yes. You might want to look at the `CDPATH` variable as well.